# Where to place custom helper classes in Flutter BLoC architecture

Tags: flutter, dart, architecture, bloc

Is there a best practice for the location of custom helper classes in Flutter using BLoC architecture?

This is my package structure:

```
/data
  /data_providers
  /models
  /repositories
/logic
  /blocs
  /cubits
/presentation
  /screens
  /widgets
/resources
```

Example: I have a custom helper class `Tuple` which is only used in my model `/data/models/User.dart`.

I see the following options:

- place class `Tuple` above or below class `User` in `/data/models/User.dart`
- create the file `/data/models/Tuple.dart` and place class `Tuple` there
- create the new package `/helpers` in the root directory, create the file `/helpers/Tuple.dart` and place class `Tuple` there
- or do you have other recommendations?

Of course all solutions are functionable. The question is: What is best practice?

Comment: hi, if you think my answer is useful, please click the "accept the answer"; if no, please give some explanations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed there is no standard best practice to put it. In my own opinion, create a separate folder called `utils` or `util` or `helper` or `helpers` and put it there. This is reasonable, since helpers are themselves not a model (so may not be put into `models/*.dart`.